# gprof on snow leopard problem

Tags: c++, osx-snow-leopard, gprof

Problem lies in the fact that gmon.out file doesnt show correct data.
All times are 0, and nothing is measured.
gmon.out file is normally generated. 
I am using eclipse ide for c++, and linking, compiling and running programs as normal.

Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [gprof on MacOS 10.6 with c++ program has call data but no timing data --- why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480944/gprof-on-macos-10-6-with-c-program-has-call-data-but-no-timing-data-why)

Answer (score 0):

Even if it were working, [it can only find certain kinds of problems, and there's a better way.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343)